# jsPlumb how to resize group

Tags: jsplumb

I am using group factory to create groups. I would like the groups to be re sizable. I know that there is a property call auto size but not sure if that would resize elements. I added resize property in my css class for group, the resize shows but it wont work as the group is draggable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery function to do this.

Apply `.resizable()` function to your field and it'll become resizable

Comment: how to use this @Malloul ?

Comment: Using `JQuery`, you can apply the `("#FIELD_TO_BE_RESIZABLE_ID").resizable()` and your field will be resizable.